# Mac standalone Xcode c++ command line project

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, command-line

I made an Xcode (Version 4.6.2) C++ command line project and I want to export it to distribute it on other macs. Preferably, I would want my export to be in a .app format but I haven't figured out how to do that yet.  I did manage to get the project's executable to run on my Mac but it doesn't work when I try it on my laptop. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a command line program, then you don't want to distribute it as an app bundle, since those are hard to call from the command line, and would require at least a little bit of Obj-C. You probably want to distribute it as an Installer package.

If your binary runs on one machine but not another, then the most likely culprits are either a mismatch of shared libraries, or compiler settings that generate code that doesn't run on all machines. Your question does not currently provide enough information to diagnose this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to export your utility using dmg. Its a standard technique. You can create dmg with your utility using `hdiutil` utility. See `man hdiutil`. Here [some examples](http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-hdiutil.html)

If you want to use separate application which will copy your utility to some place on target machine - then you should create another target in your project (application) - install app. Make your install app dependent on your utility (to build utility first). Than your install app should copy utility to its bundle. And there should be some simple code to copy the file. 

But if you want to export a project to the target machine and then build it there - its a bad idea. You should export only the executable.

Now about the executable. To build it properly you should set correct Build Settings: Architecture, SDK, target OS, etc. To help you on that we need to know for example the error whit which executable fails on your laptop, what OS version on your mac and on your laptop, etc. Usually problems are in wrong architecture and library dependencies.

Comment: I created dmg file and put my executable in it and brought it over to my laptop and got the following error in the command line: "illigal instruction logout". Any idea what this may mean?

Comment: Can't say anything concrete, looks like bug in code (buffer overflow or something). Try to google the error: there were such questions on SO already. Do you have such error without dmg?